# Get SSL Certificate 'Issued to'

Tags: powershell, ssl

I want to know how can I get Local Computer SSL certificates `Issued to` field values. I used this command to show all SSL certificates informations but it did not show me `Issued To` field

`GET-CHILDITEM -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\' –RECURSE | FORMAT-LIST –PROPERTY *`

Answer (score 3):

Does this answer your question?

```
gci Cert:\LocalMachine\my| select -expandp dnsnamelist
```

Enjoy -tom

Answer (score 3):

`IssuedTo` field seems to be dynamically generated by `certmgr.msc` based on `Subject` field.

The closest I got based on certificates I have installed on my machine was something like that:

```
$CertsDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\' –Recurse
$CertsDetail | select @{n="IssuedTo";e={(($_.Subject -split ",") |? {$_ -like "CN=*"}) -replace "CN="}}
```

What I did was to use calculated property to find first `CN=` part in `Subject` and then to remove that `CN=` part. For sure that doesn't cover all the possible scenarios but you can use it as starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and parse them from the `Issuer` field:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\' -Recurse |                                            #'# dummy comment to correct code-highlighting in SO
    Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # get at most two parts out of the $_.Issuer string
        $issuer = '{0}, {1}' -f ([regex] 'O=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value, 
                                ([regex] 'CN=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FriendlyName = $_.FriendlyName
            Issuer       = $issuer.Trim(', "')
            Subject      = $_.Subject
        }
    } | Format-List
```

On my machine it returns stuff like:

> ```
> FriendlyName : Sectigo
> Issuer       : The USERTRUST Network, USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
> Subject      : CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, S=New Jersey, C=US
>
> FriendlyName : Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
> Issuer       : The Go Daddy Group
> Subject      : OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US
>
> FriendlyName : VeriSign
> Issuer       : VeriSign
> Subject      : OU=VeriSign Commercial Software Publishers CA, O="VeriSign, Inc.", L=Internet
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Subject** property.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\' -Recurse | Format-List -Property Subject
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @Theo's example to make this approximation of the certlm.msc UI view tool for users who are asking to use that tool to cross check.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\' -Recurse |
    Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer } | 
    ForEach-Object {

        # use the same fields as certlm.msc
        $issuer = '{0}' -f ([regex] 'CN=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value
        $subject = '{0}' -f ([regex] 'CN=([^,]+)').Match($_.Subject).Groups[1].Value

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Store        = $_.PSParentPath.SubString($_.PSParentPath.IndexOf("::")+2)
            IssuedTo      = $subject.Trim(', "') #$_.Subject
            IssuedBy       = $issuer.Trim(', "')
            Expires      = $_.NotAfter
            PrivateKey      = $_.HasPrivateKey
            Exportable     = $_.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable
            Thumb        = $_.Thumbprint
        }
    } | Sort-Object -Property Store, IssuedTo | FT -AutoSize
```